# scala and abstract type "unboxing"

Tags: scala, abstract-type

Given classes

```
object A {
  type URLT = String
}

case class A(url : URLT)

class ForeignStreamWriter {
  def writeString(str: String) {}
}

trait WriterA {

  val writer : ForeignStreamWriter

  def write(src: A) {
    writer.write(src.url)
  }
}
```

how can I tell the compiler that I'm working with String - not URLT - in **writer.write(src.url)**? I can not modify signature of ForeignStreamWriter.

**UPD**

As for now I found the only solution

```
  def write(src: A) {
    writer.write(src.url.asInstanceOf[String])
  }
```

but I don't really like it.

Comment: Not sure I follow. What exactly is your compile error? and do you mean `writeString(src.url)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `import A._` in scope. By the way, your sample didn't compile without it.